# how to update a external jar with my java class file on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

In my java project, i have added some external jars. I want to update a particular jar with my java class file. Please help me how to do this.

Regards
Rajasekaran.G

Comment: is the .jar a compiled package? In other words, does the package contain .class files?

Comment: @martin,
yes, it is compiled package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jar you want to add your class to is a 3r party library, I would recommend against doing what you described (it can lead to subtle surprises and unintended side effects).

If the jar you want to update is your own, I would mode the source for the class into the project that generates that jar and it should be added automatically during the generation of the jar.

If you *really* want to do it by hand, you can unjar the external jar, add your .class file to the resulting directory structure and jar it up again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my own jar and i dont want to update this jar manually. is there any automated ways for updating this jar?

Comment: I want to know is there any options in Eclipse IDE itselt.

Comment: It depends on what project you are using.  If it does not create it automatically for you, you can use File -> Export (see [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html), for an example with pictures)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the jar independently try this,

```
jar -uvf <existingjar> <class file in appropriate folder structure as per package>
```

e.g.

```
jar -uvf current.jar  NewClass.class
```

or if your class is in some package say `com.my.util`, place your class file in `com/my/util/NewClass.class` and execute the following from prompt

```
jar -uvf current.jar  com
```

This will update the `current.jar` file.

Comment: @santhosh,
Thanks for ur reply. Is there any options in eclipse to do this instead of updating it manually?

Comment: I think there is no way to update a referenced jar in a project. You need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If its an external jar, i wonder if you can even do this? If its your own jar, follow the option given by Attila

Answer (score 0):

try to open your .jar file winrar and place your java class wherever you want on the jar.

Comment: after placing the class winrar will ask you if you want to update your jar file, say Yes.